# Parse a number inside HTML using java

Tags: java, html, string, parsing, jsoup

I have been trying to get a number from a html string, but I cannot come up with a way to do it properly, I already looked for instructions for Jsoup, but I don't really understand how it works.

This is one of the strings I have to parse:

```
<span class="b"><a href="/paline/linea/014?id_palina=76954&amp;nav=5#pal">014</a>:</span>
```

What I'm trying to get as output is 014, the name of the link. I need to get the number in a String variable, not Integer by the way.

Or this

```
<span class="b"><a href="/paline/percorso/50268?id_palina=76954&amp;nav=5#pal">08</a>:</span>
```

For the 08.

The main problem I'm finding is that two things change in the string, the number after /paline/percorso/ and the number which is the name of the link. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your samples are like this, you can do this with simple string functions:

```
final String input = "<span class=\"b\"><a href=\"/paline/linea/014?id_palina=76954&amp;nav=5#pal\">014</a>:</span>";

final int i2 = input.lastIndexOf( "</a>" );
final int i1 = input.lastIndexOf( '>', i2 ) + 1;

final String result = input.substring( i1, i2 );

System.out.println( result );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
Elements resultLinks = doc.select("span.b > a");
for (Element e:resultLinks)
    String yourText=e.text();
```

Comment: how does that help him getting the number out?

Comment: He said that he needs the number as a string. The select will return all the links. Using text() method will return him the content of the link, the string that he requested.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably try a simple regex.  Although depending on your string, it may be more complex than a simple quick and dirty regex.

```
String html = "<span class="b"><a href="/paline/linea/014?id_palina=76954&amp;nav=5#pal">014</a>:</span>"
html.replaceAll( ".*<a.*>([0-9]*)</a.*", "$1" );
```